# How can I set up the QMYSQL driver in PySide?

Tags: pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to set up the QMYSQL driver in PySide. I've tried looking at the Qt documentation but that didn't work. Is there a specific way to set the driver up?

Answer (score 0):

If your using linux you can install the driver. For ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4-sql
```

Apparently, for windows if you get the message:

```
 QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
 QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC3 QODBC QPSQL7 QPSQL
```

you have to build QMYSQL driver yourself as explained [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/sql-driver.html#qmysql).